# NoneType object is not callable django admin

Tags: python, django

I have an app in django admin, im trying to make some validations, `Transaction` model and its a parent for 2 models, `FamilyGroup` and `FamilMember`

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    number_of_family_group = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( null=True)

class FamilyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=name_choices)
    transaction =models.ForeignKey(Transaction,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='family_groups')
    
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    family_group = models.ForeignKey(FamilyGroup,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     null=True,
                                      blank=True, related_name='family_members')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Im trying to make custome validations in the `transaction` model like this

```
@property
def clean(self):
    b = FamilyGroup.objects.filter(transaction__id=self.id).count()
    if self.number_of_family_group != b:
        raise ValidationError('worng family')
```

when im trying to do this im getting an error `NoneType object is not callable`

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1641, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1558, in _changeform_view
    form_validated = form.is_valid()
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 378, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 404, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1207, in full_clean
    self.clean()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[02/Feb/2021 18:47:46] "POST /calculator/transaction/31/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 143966
```

Comment: `property` or `@property`?

Comment: `@property` sorry fiexed in the question.

Comment: You'll need to provide the traceback for us to understand what the issue is.

Comment: I added a traceback, Thank you for your interest to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `related_name='something'` to model `FamilyMember`, so you can rewrite your `clean` method like this:

```
def clean(self):
    b = self.something.count()
    if self.number_of_family_group != b:
        raise ValidationError('worng family')
```

also remember to **remove** `@property` decorator from your `clean` method.

---

hope to solve your problem.

Comment: thank you, once i removed `@Property` it worked.

Comment: happy to hear that.